# Microphone stop work on long skype call

Tags: skype, microphone

Occasionally, when I talk via skype in 30-40 minutes my partners can hear me. If there is more voice char programm opened (eg raidcall, steam chat, built-in voice chats in games ) my collocutors cant hear me too until I close skype.
What can I use to trace or fix this issue?

Ubuntu 14.10